# HTTP requests failing on mobile networks, fine on WiFi

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an WP7 application that I have been developing via the emulator. This app sends off a few web requests and waits for the responses. It works fine on the emulator but on the phone it only works on the wifi. Any ideas?

EDIT: On mobile networks the application just closes after the first reqest is made. I'm pretty sure that there is some sort of exception being thrown here as it is the only time the app would close without user input. To further aggravate the issue I live in an area where there is no mobile coverage so I cannot test with the debuger attached.

EDIT: ok tests done, it seems the first request I send comes back null. This only happens when on a cell network, it works fine on WIFI

here is the request:

```
RequestUrl = String.Format("https://www.o2online.ie/amserver/UI/Login?org=o2ext&IDToken1={0}&IDToken2={1}", UserName, Password)
```

Comment: You haven't told us what *does* happen on mobile networks.

Comment: Ah that would be an idea alright, I will edit now.

Comment: do you get a response to the request that fails?

Comment: I dont know, I can't test without signal, I am thinking the only way around this is to add in some exception handling log to file and then walk up the road to get some signal.

Comment: If it is not a problem to share - what is the URL that you pass for a web request and how big is the response?

Comment: There is a few the responses are small, I am pretty much just getting back the HTML so I can verify my request was completed. I have some handling code finished so I'll report back shortly.

Comment: Could the server no the difference between a phone on wifi or not? Other applications work fine on the cell network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it working by allowing the request to wait for the full response:

```
            _httpRequester.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
```

The next question is now. Since I only need the first 100 or so characters of the request is there any way to set a buffer size? I am using the response HTML to verify I logged in correctly. This works snappy on WiFi but not so fast on GSM (3g is fine too put plan for the worst and all that).

Answer (score 2):

I would check if WMAppManifest.xml does include the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  ...
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: can you display a messageBox inside the Application.UnhandledException handler? Or the application gets terminated without even raising an exception?

Comment: Its not failing anymore since I removed an async progressbar but I am going to leave this open until I do more tests with my messagebox code now in place.